# Snap a GeoDataFrame of points to nearest line in separate GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, gis, shapely, geopandas, fiona

I have a GeoDataFrame `events` containing only `Point` geometries and another GeoDataFrame `streets` containing all `LineString` geometries. I am trying to snap all of the points in `events` to the nearest record in `street`. I haven't found an example using two GeoDataFrames so any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: See [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256537/returns-a-point-interpolated-along-a-line-using-geopandas)  that addresses interpolating points along a line in GeoPandas. There is also a recipe for exactly what you're trying to do in [Python Geospatial Analysis Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/python-geospatial-analysis-cookbook) using the underlying shapely.interpolate